# I want to keep my recording on zoom H4nPro as long as 2-3 hours in only one file, so it doesn’t jump to the next file, causing a gap in the recording

Tags: recording, zoom

I want to record live rehearsals and performances so that they remain in one file instead of jumping on to the next one. I mostly record with the on board mics.

Comment: idk that particular recorder, but usually they split files at the 2 or 4GB boundary - 4GB because that's the maximum file size supported on FAT32, or historically at 2GB because that was the maximum partition size on FAT16.

Answer (score 2):

The file system on the card has a limited max size. Once that size is reached the recorder starts next file. There is no gap between these two files, no missed samples. If you see a gap, that is probably because an error in the program you use in your computer to stitch together the files.

If this does not work for you, it is possible to connect the H4 to a computer via USB and record on the computer. Be aware thought that not all combinations of recording software and file system on the computer will allow larger files.

--- edit added
One way to increase recording time is to decrease the recording quality. If you select mp3 instead of wav the sound is recording with less quality, but also with significantly smaller file size. One file should be able to run for at least 24 hours using mp3.